# How to use strings inside of a string for a dynamic PIVOT query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string, dynamic, pivot

I want to write a dynamic pivot query in SQL Server to spread some category across columns.

The query contains some `WHERE` filters by strings. That's why I need to write strings within strings.

This should work with '' to escape the single quotes but it does only once.

I know I could but I want to avoid saving every string in another variable like

```
@source
@id
```

As this would lead to declaration of a lot of variables in future queries where I want to filter with more `WHERE` clauses.

Here is what I tried and what the outcome was:

```
  DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
          @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
          @id    AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

--get wanted category names   
  WITH somecategories AS(
      SELECT DISTINCT
      categories AS cats
      FROM sometable
      WHERE foo = 9)
-- remove last comma
    SELECT
          @columns+=QUOTENAME(descr) + ','
    FROM
          distdescription;

SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);
SET @id = '12345'

set @query = 'SELECT * from 
            (
                select date
                    , amount
                    , id
                    , source
                    , category
                from temp
                where source = ''location''
                  and id = '''+ @id + '''
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(amount)
                for category in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
```

execute(@query)

**outcome**
works.

```
  DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
          @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

--get wanted category names   
  WITH somecategories AS(
      SELECT DISTINCT
      categories AS cats
      FROM sometable
      WHERE foo = 9)
-- remove last comma
    SELECT
          @columns+=QUOTENAME(descr) + ','
    FROM
          distdescription;


SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);

set @query = 'SELECT * from 
            (
                select date
                    , amount
                    , id
                    , source
                    , category
                from temp
                where source = ''location''
                  and id = ''12345''
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(amount)
                for category in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
```

**outcome: **

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Then I actually discovered that I don't need the id filter in the first place so I changed it to:

```
      DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
              @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX),

    --get wanted category names   
      WITH somecategories AS(
          SELECT DISTINCT
          categories AS cats
          FROM sometable
          WHERE foo = 9)
    -- remove last comma
        SELECT
              @columns+=QUOTENAME(descr) + ','
        FROM
              distdescription;

    SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);

    set @query = 'SELECT * from 
                (
                    select date
                        , amount
                        , id
                        , source
                        , category
                    from temp
                    where source = ''location''
               ) x
                pivot 
                (
                     max(amount)
                    for category in (' + @cols + ')
                ) p '
execute(@query)
```

*outcome:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Then I tried to run the query without the PIVOT command:

```
SELECT * from 
                    (
                        select date
                            , amount
                            , id
                            , source
                            , category
                        from temp
                        where source = 'location'
                   ) x
```

and

```
SELECT * from 
                    (
                        select date
                            , amount
                            , id
                            , source
                            , category
                        from temp
                        where source = 'location'
                          and id = '12345'
                   ) x
```

both work fine.

If I use

```
select @query
```

the **output** ends with:

```
SELECT some data,
       some other data,
       the content of @columns
) p
```

Where it should look like:

```
SELECT some data,
           some other data,
           the content of @columns
  FROM some table
    )x
 pivot 
            (
                 max(amount)
                for category in (' + @columns + ')
            ) p
```

So somehow a part of the PIVOT function is deleted.
I should add that the real query is much longer (a string with 4376 characters).

Comment: Did you `print` the `@Query`??

Comment: Before  `execute(@query)` write a code `Print @query` !!!

Comment: Instead of `'...id = '''+ @id + '''...'` you should be parametrising your dynamic statement an using `sp_executesql`. I *assume* something like `'... id = @id ...'` and then `EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@id int', @id;` Injecting unsanitised values into a dynamic statement is an awful idea.

Comment: The print stops before reaching the end of the query.
if I use: 
and id = ''12345'' 
it is a different line where the print stops then when I simply delete that line but both times its in a later part of the query nowhere near that line...

Comment: Then use `SELECT`, @Sebban . `PRINT` can only return up to 4,000 characters.

Comment: Thanks Select helps to get the query. Let me see if I can debug it now.

Comment: Okay I used SELECT and it seems the @columns variable replaces a few lines of codes in the end of the query.

Comment: Okay I used SELECT and it seems the @columns variable replaces a few lines of codes in the end of the query.

the @query end with `SELECT some data; some other data, the content of @columns) p`

but the string actually is formatted like: `SELECT some data; some other data, more data FROM  sometable LEFTJOIN sometbale ON some other table) X PIVOT(  max(amount)
                    for category in (' + @columns + ')
                ) p '`

with `AND id = ''12345''`

Comment: is there a max amount of characters in string variables?

Comment: >Instead of '...id = '''+ @id + '''...' you should be parametrising your dynamic >statement an using sp_executesql. I assume something like '... id = @id ...' and >then EXEC sp_executesql `@query`, N'@id int', @id; Injecting unsanitised values >into a dynamic statement is an awful idea. 

But id is saved as a string in the db so it is actually NVARCHAR(MAX) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36081/write-differences-between-varchar-and-nvarchar

> "You need to be sure that you prefix Unicode string literals with an N
>   prefix."

So `SET @query =N'...'` solved the problem.